# Type casting and automatic type promotion in Java

Tags: java

Let's consider some simple expressions in Java.

```
byte var=0;

var=(byte)(var+1);
```

---

Here, in the above statement, obviously type casting is needed because of automatic type promotion.

The evaluation of the expression **(var+1)** is automatically promoted to int hence, must explicitly be cast to byte to assign the outcome of it to a byte variable on the right of the assignment which is **var**

---

Now, let's consider the following statement in Java.

```
var++;
```

This is somewhat equivalent to the previous statement and should have needed a cast though it works without a cast. Why?

---

Even the following statement doesn't require a cast. Why?

```
byte x=var++;
```

Comment: It's only equivalent if you couldn't add a (byte) 1 to var, but you can--why wouldn't ++ use the correct type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification, §15.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2):

> The type of the postfix increment expression is the type of the variable.

On the other hand, for the expression `var + 1`, the following rules apply ([JLS, §5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)):

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order, using [widening conversion (§5.1.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to convert operands as necessary:
>
> • If any of the operands is of a reference type, [unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) is performed. Then:
> • If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> • Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> • Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> • Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

So adding two numerical types will never give a result narrower than an `int`.