# Bit Twiddling: Encoding Unsigned Primitives

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Below is a class that encodes **unsigned** primitive types as a byte array and returns an encoded byte array as a decimal string. I understand conceptually how `encodeIntBigEndian` & `byteArrayToDecimalString` work. However, I'd appreciate clarity on:

> 1. Why/how shifting the `val` by `((size - i - 1) * Byte.SIZE)` produces an unsigned java byte value.
> 2. Also, why does applying a byte mask of `0xff` convert the byte to a decimal string value.

```
public class BruteForceCoding {
 private static byte byteVal = 101; // one hundred and one
 private static short shortVal = 10001; // ten thousand and one
 private static int intVal = 100000001; // one hundred million and one
 private static long longVal = 1000000000001L;// one trillion and one

 private final static int BSIZE = Byte.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
 private final static int SSIZE = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
 private final static int ISIZE = Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
 private final static int LSIZE = Long.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;

 private final static int BYTEMASK = 0xFF; // 8 bits
 public static String byteArrayToDecimalString(byte[] bArray) {
  StringBuilder rtn = new StringBuilder();
  for (byte b : bArray) {
   rtn.append(b & BYTEMASK).append(" ");
  }
  return rtn.toString();
 }

 public static int encodeIntBigEndian(byte[] dst, long val, int offset, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   dst[offset++] = (byte) (val >> ((size - i - 1) * Byte.SIZE));
  }
  return offset;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  byte[] message = new byte[BSIZE + SSIZE + ISIZE + LSIZE];
  // Encode the fields in the target byte array
  int offset = encodeIntBigEndian(message, byteVal, 0, BSIZE);
  offset = encodeIntBigEndian(message, shortVal, offset, SSIZE);
  offset = encodeIntBigEndian(message, intVal, offset, ISIZE);
  encodeIntBigEndian(message, longVal, offset, LSIZE);
  System.out.println("Encoded message: " + byteArrayToDecimalString(message));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It doesn't, by itself. What it does is it shifts the value down by units of one byte. However, when combined with the cast to `(byte)`, which discards the high bits, this amounts to a shift-and-mask operation which extracts individual bytes from the value.

2) It doesn't. It masks off the high bits, leaving the low eight bits (one byte) of the value -- the same operation that casting to `byte` performed in the previous case. However, by default rendering a byte as a string produces a string containing the decimal number expressing its binary value (from 0 to 255), and that's happening implicitly when .append() is called.

Comment: So, if I understand applying the `0xFF` or `11111111` bytemask clears the higher bits -- essentially negating the implicitly applied sign during conversion to the decimal string representation of the binary value?

Comment: Yep. For example, 0xFFFE (all 1's except the lowest bit) is the 2's-complement representation of -2. Bitwise-ANDing it with 0xFF will yield 0x00FE, the 2's-complement representation of 254. The fact that the high bit is the sign bit in 2's-complement integers isn't meaningful for bit-twiddling purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why/how shifting the val by `((size - i - 1) * Byte.SIZE)` produces an unsigned java byte value.

It doesn't.  `>>` is a [sign extending shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811319/difference-between-and) so it doesn't change the sign of its left argument.  `>>>` by a non-zero number of bits is guaranteed to produce a non-negative result, so could be considered having an unsigned output.

Either way, as soon as it's cast to a `byte`, the value is signed again since Java has no unsigned byte type.

> Also, why does applying a byte mask of 0xff convert the byte to a decimal string value.

It doesn't.

Decimal conversion happens at

> ```
> rtn.append(b & BYTEMASK).append(" ")
> ```

`(b & BYTEMASK)` has type `int` due to [type-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116814/20394) and is a value in the range [0, 256), and `StringBuilder.append(int)` is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28int%29) as appending the decimal representation of its argument.

---

UPDATE:

To understand

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
>   dst[offset++] = (byte) (val >> ((size - i - 1) * Byte.SIZE));
> }
> ```

consider what it does for a `size` of 4 which corresponds to a 4-byte/32-bit java `int`.

```
dst[offset  ] = (byte) (val >> 24);  // (byte) 0x??????01 == 0x01
dst[offset+1] = (byte) (val >> 16);  // (byte) 0x????0123 == 0x23
dst[offset+2] = (byte) (val >>  8);  // (byte) 0x??012345 == 0x45
dst[offset+3] = (byte) (val >>  0);  // (byte) 0x01234567 == 0x67
```

so given int `0x01234567` it will put into `dst` the bytes `0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67` in order.

Comment: `encodeIntBigEndian` is supposed to emulate writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I understand that the method shifts the value to the right by a byte and then clears the higher bits, but what does doing so accomplish in terms of encoding the value as a byte?